# AudioJS: play only html5 audio at time per page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm currently using the simple AudioJs script which is very easy to integrate, but If I have multiple audio files in the same page, I wan the user to be able to click play on any and listening without the need to stop the previous file first... ti basically i need a toggle that says "stop all" THEN play this

any help on how to implement this?

i tried

```
    $.each($('audio'), function() {
        this.pause();
    });
```

but this doesn't reverse the button and the status "playing" of each instance created by AudioJs

Comment: Have you tried calling `.pause()` on all audio nodes in `document`? Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: i tried Jquery each and yes i can stop them, but then it conflicts with AudioJS instructions, because i cannot set playing=false for each instance created by AudioJS

Comment: Have not tried `AudioJS`. Does the library use `AudioContext` to  playback media?

Comment: not sure... http://kolber.github.io/audiojs/docs/

Answer (score 0):

The general trick for such functionality is to bind  `onplay` event on all the players; when you play one it would trigger now you pause all players except the one on which `onplay` got triggered , but problem here is audiojs doesn't provide audio events (it only provides methods to play ,pause etc)in its wrapper objects.But there is something you can do: each player object will have a reference to its corresponding HTML5 `<audio>` element (that's actually playing the mp3) you can use this and bind directly on that using `element` property .

1.bind `onplay` on all the players

```
allAud = a.createAll();
for(var i=0; i<allAud.length;i++)
{ 
    allAud[i].element.onplay = function pauseOthers();
}
```

2.when onplay triggers loop over all player's `<audio>` and pause all except the one on which event was triggered (using audiojs wrapper `pause()` method

```
function pauseOthers() { 
    for(var j=0; j<allAud.length;j++)
    {
        if(allAud[j].element != this)  //pause all except the one being played
        allAud[j].pause(); // can also use `this.pause()` , but better let audiojs do that incase it's handling some play/pause animation
    }
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/rqsxxjmd/